# Yahoo Weather API in swift Extra argument in oauth request

Tags: ios, swift, arguments, yahoo, weather

I'm trying to integrate the Yahoo API service in my IOS app (https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html#oauth-swift). I had no problems for android, but now I'm experiencing a compiler issue with swift and Xcode11.
I added the Oauth pod: https://cocoapods.org/pods/OAuthSwift, and the code in the documentation:

```
import Foundation
/*
See https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift for information on
including this OAuth library in your project.
*/
import OAuthSwift

enum YahooWeatherAPIResponseType:String {
    case json = "json"
    case xml = "xml"
}

enum YahooWeatherAPIUnitType:String {
    case imperial = "f"
    case metric = "c"
}

fileprivate struct YahooWeatherAPIClientCredentials {
    var appId = ""
    var clientId = ""
    var clientSecret = ""
}

class YahooWeatherAPI {
    // Configure the following with your values.
    private let credentials = YahooWeatherAPIClientCredentials(appId: "-your-app-id-", clientId: "-your-client-id-", clientSecret: "-your-client-secret-")

    private let url:String = "https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss"
    private let oauth:OAuth1Swift?

    public static let shared = YahooWeatherAPI()

    private init() {
        self.oauth = OAuth1Swift(consumerKey: self.credentials.clientId, consumerSecret: self.credentials.clientSecret)
    }

    private var headers:[String:String] {
        return [
            "X-Yahoo-App-Id": self.credentials.appId
        ]
    }

    /// Requests weather data by location name.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - location: the name of the location, i.e. sunnyvale,ca
    ///   - failure: failure callback
    ///   - success: success callback
    ///   - responseFormat: .xml or .json. default is .json.
    ///   - unit: metric or imperial units. default = .imperial

    public func weather(location:String, failure: @escaping (_ error: OAuthSwiftError) -> Void, success: @escaping (_ response: OAuthSwiftResponse) -> Void, responseFormat:YahooWeatherAPIResponseType = .json, unit:YahooWeatherAPIUnitType = .imperial) {
        self.makeRequest(parameters: ["location":location, "format":responseFormat.rawValue, "u":unit.rawValue], failure: failure, success: success)
    }


    /// Requests weather data by woeid (Where on Earth ID)
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - woeid: The location's woeid
    ///   - failure: failure callback
    ///   - success: success callback
    ///   - responseFormat: .xml or .json. default is .json.
    ///   - unit: metric or imperial units. default = .imperial

    public func weather(woeid:String, failure: @escaping (_ error: OAuthSwiftError) -> Void, success: @escaping (_ response: OAuthSwiftResponse) -> Void, responseFormat:YahooWeatherAPIResponseType = .json, unit:YahooWeatherAPIUnitType = .imperial) {
        self.makeRequest(parameters: ["woeid":woeid, "format":responseFormat.rawValue, "u":unit.rawValue], failure: failure, success: success)
    }


    /// Requests weather data by latitude and longitude
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - lat: latitude
    ///   - lon: longiture
    ///   - failure: failure callback
    ///   - success: success callback
    ///   - responseFormat: .xml or .json. default is .json.
    ///   - unit: metric or imperial units. default = .imperial
    public func weather(lat:String, lon:String, failure: @escaping (_ error: OAuthSwiftError) -> Void, success: @escaping (_ response: OAuthSwiftResponse) -> Void, responseFormat:YahooWeatherAPIResponseType = .json, unit:YahooWeatherAPIUnitType = .imperial) {
        self.makeRequest(parameters: ["lat":lat, "lon":lon, "format":responseFormat.rawValue, "u":unit.rawValue], failure: failure, success: success)
    }


    /// Performs the API request with the OAuthSwift client
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - parameters: Any URL parameters to pass to the endpoint.
    ///   - failure: failure callback
    ///   - success: success callback
    private func makeRequest(parameters:[String:String], failure: @escaping (_ error: OAuthSwiftError) -> Void, success: @escaping (_ response: OAuthSwiftResponse) -> Void) {
        self.oauth?.client.request(self.url, method: .GET, parameters: parameters, headers: self.headers, body: nil, checkTokenExpiration: true, success: success, failure: failure)
    }

}
```

BUT I'm getting the compiler error "Extra argument "failure" in the last makerequest function (see attachment).

```
  private func makeRequest(parameters:[String:String], failure: @escaping (_ error: OAuthSwiftError) -> Void, success: @escaping (_ response: OAuthSwiftResponse) -> Void) {
        self.oauth?.client.request(self.url, method: .GET, parameters: parameters, headers: self.headers, body: nil, checkTokenExpiration: true, success: success, failure: **failure**)
    }
```

[Compiler error][1]

Does anybody have experience with Oauth and this kind of issues? Can anybody help me?

Many thanks in advance

This is how the Yahooweather Oauth request should be called (thanks to jawadAli):

```
  public func weather(lat:String, lon:String, responseFormat:YahooWeatherAPIResponseType = .json, unit:YahooWeatherAPIUnitType = .imperial,completion: OAuthSwiftHTTPRequest.CompletionHandler?) {

         self.makeRequest(parameters: ["lat":lat, "lon":lon, "format":responseFormat.rawValue, "u":unit.rawValue], completion: completion)
    }

    private func makeRequest(parameters:[String:String], completion: OAuthSwiftHTTPRequest.CompletionHandler?) {

        self.oauth?.client.request(self.url, method: .GET, parameters: parameters, headers: self.headers, body: nil, checkTokenExpiration: true, completionHandler: completion)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Use OAuth2Swift function

```
self.client.request(accessTokenUrl, method: .POST, parameters: parameters, headers: finalHeaders, checkTokenExpiration: false, completionHandler: completionHandler)
```

Actual Parameters of Client Request are

```
func request(_ url: URLConvertible, method: OAuthSwiftHTTPRequest.Method, parameters: OAuthSwift.Parameters = [:], headers: OAuthSwift.Headers? = nil, body: Data? = nil, checkTokenExpiration: Bool = true, completionHandler completion: OAuthSwiftHTTPRequest.CompletionHandler?) -> OAuthSwiftRequestHandle?
```

Its taking Completion handler instead of success Failure

hope it solve your issue

check out this code ... You need to send escaping completion handler rather than success or failure separately

```
fileprivate func requestOAuthAccessToken(withParameters parameters: OAuthSwift.Parameters, headers: OAuthSwift.Headers? = nil, completionHandler completion: @escaping TokenCompletionHandler) -> OAuthSwiftRequestHandle? {

        let completionHandler: OAuthSwiftHTTPRequest.CompletionHandler = { [weak self] result in
            guard let this = self else {
                OAuthSwift.retainError(completion)
                return
            }
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                let responseJSON: Any? = try? response.jsonObject(options: .mutableContainers)

                let responseParameters: OAuthSwift.Parameters

                if let jsonDico = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                    responseParameters = jsonDico
                } else {
                    responseParameters = response.string?.parametersFromQueryString ?? [:]
                }

                guard let accessToken = responseParameters["access_token"] as? String else {
                    let message = NSLocalizedString("Could not get Access Token", comment: "Due to an error in the OAuth2 process, we couldn't get a valid token.")
                    completion(.failure(.serverError(message: message)))
                    return
                }

                if let refreshToken = responseParameters["refresh_token"] as? String {
                    this.client.credential.oauthRefreshToken = refreshToken.safeStringByRemovingPercentEncoding
                }

                if let expiresIn = responseParameters["expires_in"] as? String, let offset = Double(expiresIn) {
                    this.client.credential.oauthTokenExpiresAt = Date(timeInterval: offset, since: Date())
                } else if let expiresIn = responseParameters["expires_in"] as? Double {
                    this.client.credential.oauthTokenExpiresAt = Date(timeInterval: expiresIn, since: Date())
                }

                this.client.credential.oauthToken = accessToken.safeStringByRemovingPercentEncoding
                completion(.success((this.client.credential, response, responseParameters)))
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
```

change your method definition to

```
private func makeRequest(parameters:[String:String], completion: @escaping TokenCompletionHandler) -> OAuthSwiftRequestHandle?)
```

this TokenCompletionHandler is a ResultType .... you can add switch of failure or success cases...let me know if you need further help

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm not home currently. Is this function embedded? Could you link me the code/pod if not?

Comment: This function is in `OAuthSwiftClient` 
i am using same Pod downloaded from your provided link

Comment: and appreciate my effort please =)

Comment: Not resolved yet, but thanks for the support, see details

Comment: Sir I just don't get it and I'm having headache trying to code without getting errors from the compiler. I'm not so familiar with swift and I don't understand why it is so difficult to make a oauth request working. I'd be grateful if you'd send me the code above without errors. I would understand if you won't do that. Thanks

Comment: can you connect via teamviewer ? i will fix this on your end

Comment: Teamviewer doesnt work ... you screen was not visible to me

Comment: Send me project if you can

Comment: https://files.fm/u/4knszbpe      here I'm basically trying to get weather info and print it on a textview. You can't actually get data from yahoo because I didn't include the API id and pass (tell me if you need these necessarily), but I'd be glad if you send me the project back without compiler errors. Thanks for your patience

Comment: here is the project ... with what you want to achieve brother ... let me know if you face any difficulty

Comment: please give your feedback